# php Update via loop

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, phpmyadmin

When users fill in a form they also fill in the number of axles. the information gets send to the table: "train_information" when submitted. The row axles is a FK and also gets send in the table "axle".
The table axle looks like this after insert:

[image: database table]

Now i want to be able to update the distance (Wich is NULL right now). 
I do this by showing the number of axles and make a field box of them:

```
                 <tr> 
                    <?php      
                        foreach($show_axle as $axleposition){ ?>
                        <input type='hidden' name='axle_id' value='<?php echo $axleposition['axle_id']?>'>
                        <td><input type='text' name='distance' id = "<?php echo $axleposition['axle_id']?>"placeholder="<?php echo $axleposition['axle']?>"></td>

                        <?php
                        } 
                    ?>
                </tr>
```

As you can see i show it in a form. The form action is:

```
<form method='POST' action='axle_update.php'>
```

So when they press submit, they go to axle_update.php wich looks like this:

```
<?php
    ?><pre><?php print_r($_POST) ?> </pre> <?php 

    $update_axle = $database->update_axles();
?>
```

(The pre is for myself to see what gets send)

This kinda works. becuase when i have for example 12 rows (See image). it only updates the last row. Now this is because the name of the hidden field is the same everywhere. But i don't know how to change that (In the query).

***EDIT:***

Sorry forgot the update_axles:

```
function update_axles() {
        $sql = "UPDATE axle SET distance = :distance WHERE axle_id = :axle_id";
        $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $sth->bindParam(':axle_id', $_POST['axle_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sth->bindParam(":distance", $_POST['distance'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->execute();
    }
```

Comment: Show us `$database->update_axles()`.

Comment: Your binding order is incorrect.

Comment: Can you tell me what is incorrect about it @EternalHour ?? Because it updates. but only the last row. and that is becuase the name is the same everywhere. (See hidden field)

Comment: Ah nevermind, you are using named placeholders so the order doesn't matter.

Comment: _“But i don't know how to change that (In the query)”_ – what do you mean, in the query? The input fields are not part of your query, so you can not change their names “in the query”. If you want to pass multiple parameters by the same name, then for PHP you must use square brackets in the name, like `name="axle_id[]"`. You can also specify the key of the resulting array upfront, `name="axle_id[0]"`, `name="axle_id[1]"` etc. – that will get you an array that you then can loop through.

Comment: Your inputs are overwritten everytime you add another input. Use `name='axle_id[]'` and then loop through your `$_POST` on `update_axles()`

Comment: Can someone please make a little example since i don't realy understand it. Or help me via chat??

Comment: I did: 'name='axle_id[<?php echo $axleposition['axle_id']?>]'' so now the name is axle_id[12] for example. But how do i pass this through to where to query is executed???

Comment: Now that you have your axle values in an array, you can loop through it and repeatedly call `$sth->bindParam(...)` for each axle's data followed by `$sth->execute()` in your function `update_axles`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inputs are overwritten every time you add another input.

To solve this, use an input array. As follows;

```
<tr> 
<?php      
  foreach($show_axle as $axleposition){ ?>
       <input type='hidden' name='axle_id[<?php echo $axleposition['axle_id']?>]' value='<?php echo $axleposition['axle_id']?>'>
       <td><input type='text' name='distance[<?php echo $axleposition['axle_id']?>]' id = "<?php echo $axleposition['axle_id']?>"placeholder="<?php echo $axleposition['axle']?>"></td>
<?php
  } 
?>
</tr>
```

Now, when you POST your form, you will have an associative array.

Now all you have to do is call `$database->update_axles()` in a loop, passing the ID and the values.

<sup>**Note:** Depending on how big your input is, don't pass it in to a loop, as querying in a loop is advised against!</sup>

```
foreach($_POST['axle_id'] as $id) {
    $update_axle = $database->update_axles($id);
}
```

And finally, change your method to accept those to parameters, and modify your query.

```
function update_axles($id) {
  $sql = "UPDATE axle SET distance = :distance WHERE axle_id = :axle_id";
  $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
  $sth->bindParam(':axle_id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $sth->bindParam(":distance", $_POST['distance'][$id], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $sth->execute();
}
```

Comment: Very well explained answer.